# Can palmiers be refrigerated/frozen overnight?

Tags: baking, freezing, refrigerator

I want to make [palmiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmier) and refrigerate or freeze them overnight then bake them in the morning. Can i do that, or would they not turn out right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to cut them, wrap them up, and freeze them to be baked and served the next day without a problem.